# Android Studio IDE exception can't open Layout Resources xml files

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio is throwing an null pointer exception related to the Android Support plugin when opening.  As a result I can't open layout resources xml files.

I've tried

1. Invalidating Caches/ and restart
2. Cleaning/rebuilding project
3. Disabling Android SDK support plugin

Any help would be appreciated.Stack trace is below.

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>       at com.android.ide.common.resources.FileResourceNameValidator.getErrorTextForNameWithoutExtension(FileResourceNameValidator.java:135)
>       at com.android.ide.common.resources.FileResourceNameValidator.getErrorTextForFileResource(FileResourceNameValidator.java:117)
>       at com.android.ide.common.resources.FileResourceNameValidator.validate(FileResourceNameValidator.java:48)
>       ...

Comment: Did you delete value in string.xml?

Comment: No everything is there as normal.  I just can't open any of the layout files.  They are still on the disk and can be opened in the explorer, just not in android studio when I click them.

Comment: Solved!  Somehow I accidentally deleted one of the layout files filename.  It was just 
.xml. No name! I was able to revert the change and afterwards I could open all the layout resource files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, I think you should make sure you have every files in your project directories. Try to debug buy going to Analyze --> Inspect Code

and let it run for a while. Any errors will be marked as red. Check it if one of the files have missing references like your case above. More can be found here,

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#studio and;

[How Do We Configure Android Studio to Run Its Lint on Every Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631131/how-do-we-configure-android-studio-to-run-its-lint-on-every-build)